How to manually set constant keyframe animation between set keyframes
I'd like to know how to manually make the keyframes on the timeline to be constant like in the dope sheet editor.

I have a motion of an object rotating every 90 degrees. Every 20 keyframes the object rotates. I'm trying to figure out how to make the yellow line in between the keyframes so the object doesnt animate until the next keyframe.
Sometimes when I insert a keyframe the yellow line appears, and sometimes it doesnt. It's like I'm doing something by luck, but cannot understand why its happening.
Lots of tutorials are showing this yellow line, but its only for the thumbnail.
Someone please explain.


The yellow bar just means that the keyframes before and after have the same value.
So, it's as simple as go to the initial frame, set keyframe with a rotation value, go to the final frame, set keyframe with the same rotation value.

Setting a constant interpolation to the initial frame has the same animation result, but the start and end keyframes are NOT the same value, so no yellow bar.

I'm feeling embarrassed it was this simple... Thanks for your prompt reply.
